# ListLinePlot not plotting full data

Tags: plotting

I browsed the different ListLinePlot questions and bug posts, but couldn't find one addressing this problem - it's possible I missed it though. Here's hoping it has a simple answer!

I'm using Mathematica 8 because that's what's installed on the cluster I work on (I can't ask them to upgrade it), and when plotting using ListLinePlot, I've noticed that my data inevitably gets cut off in the y-direction, where it is fully plotted using just ListPlot. It's a lot easier to see the trends I need to check using ListLinePlot, though, so this is a bit of a problem.

Here's an image showing said cut off, I changed the y-axis manually and plotted using both ListPlot and ListLinePlot just to confirm that yes, it's actually not plotting that top part at all using ListLinePlot.

[image: ]]

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: Put `PlotRange -> All` inside both the `ListPlot` and `ListLinePlot` commands, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: fyi you do not need to overlay plots to get a lines-with-markers.  Use `ListLinePlot[..., PlotMarkers -> Automatic]`  or  `ListPlot[...,Joined->True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]`

Comment: @march, that did indeed fix it - why does PlotRange _outside_ the ListLinePlot chop the y-axis range as opposed to inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@march kindly supplied the answer, that placing PlotRange->All *inside* the ListLinePlot command would fix the problem. I'm still not sure why, but I'll take it!

(Also, thank you to @george2079 for his information about adding plot markers, I wasn't aware of those, and they will be useful at a later time.)

Comment: With the `PlotRange` outside the `Plots` do their own autoranging independently. `Show`'s `PlotRange` takes affect only after the plots have been generated. You should probalbly see whats happening if you look at the `ListLinePlot` by itself.  Why `ListPlot` and `ListLinePlot` decided on different ranges for the same data is a good question.

Comment: George, that's what I had done originally - which is why I'm confused. I only added the ListPlot to illustrate that ListLinePlot was in fact cutting off my data. When I plotted ListLinePlot on its own with PlotRange->All outside the brackets ( Show[ListLinePlot[afpeaks], PlotRange->All] ), it still cut it off.

Comment: right, the `PlotRange` option to `Show` does not "trickle down" to `ListLinePlot`. The plot is generated using whatever heuristic `ListLinePlot` uses for auto ranging (pretty poor choice in this case), then `Show` expands the range, but by then the data is cut off.